# Page reload on a dynamic route empties Vuex store (NuxtJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

My `Nuxt` pages are ordered like so:

```
pages
  \ agencies
     _agency.vue
  error.vue
  index.vue
```

Where `_agency.vue` displays data stored in my `store`, specifically, my `agencies` array:

```
// store/index.js

import Vuex from 'vuex';

const createStore = () =>
  new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      agencies: []
    },
    mutations: {
      changeAgencies(state, agencies) {
        state.agencies = agencies.sort(
          (agencyA, agencyB) =>
            agencyA.weather.currently.cloudCover - agencyB.weather.currently.cloudCover,
        );
      }          
    }
  });

export default createStore;
```

Said array is filled in the `index` page using the `fetch` method.

Everything works fine except when I navigate to /agencies/myAgency and reload the page, which gives me the following error:

> Cannot read property 'weather' of undefined

As if the data from my store was gone on reload.
Now I know that the data does not persist between reloads so I'm trying to use [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) in order to solve my problem but to no avail.

Is the source of my problem what I've stated above? And how may I solve it with `NuxtJS`?

Comment: Any reason why you're creating your store explicitly vs. Nuxt modules mode [https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#modules-mode]? I find it cleaner and you can use modules mode even if you just go with using `store/index.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on reload the data from store will be gone. The proper way would be if the data is needed for whole app -> load it in [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) action

If the data need of few pages, you just should check if the data is available and if its not available load it in [fetch](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/) method.

You could also try to use vuex perrsisted state, but it can have its own quirks. https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/54#issuecomment-414605839

Answer (score 0):

do like this then your problem will solve

> npm install vuex-persistedstate

```
// store/index.js

import Vuex from 'vuex';
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
const createStore = () =>
  new Vuex.Store({
plugins: [createPersistedState()],
    state: {
      agencies: []
    },
    mutations: {
      changeAgencies(state, agencies) {
        state.agencies = agencies.sort(
          (agencyA, agencyB) =>
            agencyA.weather.currently.cloudCover - agencyB.weather.currently.cloudCover,
        );
      }          
    }
  });

export default createStore;
```